# Did not use urllib.request but keep getting strange results about it

Tags: python

I am trying to crawl a website with the codes below. I just copied the codes from a training material. There is no traceback popping up but I could not get the correct result.

**Codes:**

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

url="https://www.zhihu.com/explore"
headers={"User-Agent":"'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'"}

html=requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
doc=pq(html)

items=doc(".explore-tab.feed-item").items()
for item in items:
    question=item.find("h2").text()
    author=item.find(".author-link-line").text()
    answer=pq(item.find(".content").html()).text()
    file=open("explore.txt","a",encoding="utf-8")

    file.write("\n".join([question,author,answer]))
    file.write("\n"+"="*50+'\n')

    file.close()
```

**Results:**

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.baidu.com', path='/index.html', params='user', query='id=5', fragment='comment')
<class 'urllib.parse.ParseResult'>
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.baidu.com', path='/index.html', params='user', query='id=5', fragment='comment')
```

I could not find the bug. I have not used urllib.parse at all in this program.
Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Sophie

Comment: Please use block code formatting (```) instead of inline code formatting (`) to format code.  This makes code reading easy. 
Also, please post the output written into _explore.txt_ along with any output written to the screen.  This helps other help you :)

Comment: Please describe what result are you expecting and what you see instead. What did you try yourself to figure out why? BTW, whatever training you are taking, it seems not to be a good one because the training material isn't idiomatic Python itself.

Comment: Looks like `pyquery` uses `urllib` internally, and that might be what's being confused.

Comment: The result for your `answer` variable is wrapped in the `pq` method, but the results for `question` and `author` are not. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Venkatesh-Prasad Ranganath Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry I am aware of the format issues but this is my first time of using stack overflow. Sorry for that. I would try my best to prevent similar issues..

Comment: @satoru Thank you for the answer. I am trying to crawl a web ("https://www.zhihu.com/explore") and thus I am expecting to get the content from the page (or traceback if there is bug). However, I am getting neither of them. Instead, I am getting what is shown in the "Results" of my question. (1) There is no Traceback shown in the result so I think there is nothing wrong with the code itself? (2) But I could not get the expected result..I tried to look it up on google but find nothing, that's why I signed up stack overflow and came here....

Comment: @SophieSophie In your code you are writing what you fetch and parse from the page to a file called `explore.txt`. What you pasted in the question seems to be part of the stdout. What's in the file?